# How to get total number of frames in a video.mp4 using Qt Multimedia

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

**Scenario**
I am using [QMediaPlayer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html) to a display a video on a [VideoOutput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html).
*Works well*.

I do a `MyQMediaPlayerPtr->setMedia(sample_video.mp4)` & I have full control on that video playback.

I am using `QMediaPlayer`'s `setPostion` to seek a random frame from the video. However it will very efficient if I could query the total number of frames in that `sample_video.mp4` using `QMediaPlayer` or some other `Qt Multimedia` component.

**Question:**
*How* can I get the *number of frames* in the `sample_video.mp4`? Is it possible using a `QMediaPlayer` API?
*If* not, *which utility* in `Qt Multimedia` could get me this information?

Comment: Does Qt6 have anything to offer in the context of this question?